# Hypercycle are not lines

Tags: hyperbolic-geometry

I was trying to show in $\mathbb{H}$ -Poincaré half-plane model- that hypercycles defined for a given line $l$ and a given $a$ in $\mathbb{R}$ as $$H(l)=\{z \in \mathbb{H} : d_{\mathbb{H}}(z,l)=a \} $$
are not lines.

To prove something I tried to argue that given that $Mob(\mathbb{H})$ acts transitvely on the lines of $\mathbb{H}$ I can find the hypercycles of the imaginary axis and via the $\gamma \in Mob(\mathbb{H})$ that maps my line in the imaginary axis i can state $$H(l)=\gamma^{-1}(H(\gamma(l))$$

Where I'm using the fact that a Möbius transformations preserves distances. At this point I defined [already here i have doubts] $d_{\mathbb{H}}(z,l)$ for a given $z \in \mathbb{H}$ and a line $l$ as the inf in k of the distances $d_{\mathbb{H}}(z,w)$ with $w \in l$.

Given this and the general assumption $z=a+bi$ and $w=ki$  i'm left with trying to calculate the inf of $$arccosh(1+\frac{|a+(b-k)i|^{2}}{2bk})$$

EDITED FROM HERE TO SHOW MORE WORK:

given that arccosh is a monotone function i need to find the inf of $$\frac{a^{2}+{b}^{2}}{2bk}+\frac{k}{2b}-1$$

taking the derivative I'm looking to the zeroes of:

$$\frac{-2a^{2}-2b^{2}+k^{2}b}{2bk^{2}}$$

solving and remembering that i need $k>0$ i get $k=(\frac{2(a^{2}+b^{2})}{b})^{\frac{1}{2}}$

looking now for the $a+bi$ such that for a given $p$ we have:
$$ d_{\mathbb{H}}(a+bi,(\frac{2(a^{2}+b^{2})}{b})^{\frac{1}{2}}i)=p $$

expanding this i got an expression of $z,z^{*}$ that is not a standard form for a line in the plane and it should end the exercise.

Is any of this correct? There is any "distance from a given point to a given line" standard formula in hyperbolic geometry? Thanks for any help and hint.

Comment: It is even simpler than this: Hypercycles are never connected, but lines are.

Comment: Ok, the fact that arccosh should help in my tractation. About connection you mean as they are symmetric in respect to my line?

Comment: Do you know what this means for a topological space to be [connected](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_space)?

Comment: Yes but I think in this case is not a "real" answer. In the real cases i have two parallel lines, they are not connected but are "lines". I think the question should be answered with this pov.

Comment: Then you should update your question asking for a proof that the two connected components of the hypercycles are non-geodesic (provided, of course, that $a>0$). And in this case the real answer lies in the description of hyperbolic geodesics in the upper half-plane model, from which it follows that any two points in the boundary circle lie in the closure of a unique geodesic, from what it follows that components of a hypercycle are never geodesic.

Comment: I showed quite a bit of my work...

Comment: If $a$ is a positive real constant, $f(z) = a z$ is also a Mobius transformation preserving the upper half plane  and preserving distances.

Comment: On that note, what is the distance of $3+4i$  from the imaginary axis?

Comment: According to my computation it should be $arccos(1+\frac{3+16+25/2-sqrt(2)10}{sqrt(2)20})$. Besides it not looking good I don't understand your observation about f(z)=az, I'm sorry...

Comment: Your formulation of the question suggests that you want an analytic answer (using calculus/analysis). But would you be open to a synthetic answer (using geometry/symmetry)?

Comment: I would like to know if my work is wrong or could be recovered but for sure any way to attach the problem is welcomed

Comment: I did not check your computations but, from what is written: (1) your computations are insufficient for the proof, (2) there is a much more direct argument that I sketched above, which is based on the description of a hypercycle as the union of two disjoint circular arcs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will now answer to the questions, leaving my work in the original post to show my mistakes.

My $k$ was wrong, and the right calculations shows that the inf is taken in $$k=\sqrt{a^{2}+b^{2}}$$ Now I'm left trying do describe the locus of points in the form $a+bi$ such that for a given $p$ $$d_{\mathbb{H}}(a+bi,(\sqrt{a^{2}+b^{2}})i)=p$$
Now using the Poincare half-plane metric i get to show that $\frac{|z|}{Im z}=p$.
Showing that my hypercycle is defined given an angle and it is an euclidean line passign through the origin and the given point, clearly not an hyperbolic line.